# Printer changing temperature after selecting file

Tags: abs, monoprice-maker-select

I have just got a Monoprice Maker Select 3d printer (which is really just a Wanhao Duplicator i3).

I want to print a model that came on the included SD card (`1.gcode`) with ABS filament. I first press "`Preheat ABS`" and wait for the display to show the correct temperatures, 245°C for the extruder and 90°C for the print bed. Then, I mount the SD card and select the file to print.

However, once I do that, the "goal" temperatures change to 195°C for the extruder and 50°C for the print bed, and the temperatures reported by the printer gradually go down as the printer waits for it to match the "goal" temperature. This results in a failed print, with the filament sticking to the extruder in a clump.

What is going on here? I am trying PLA with the same file, and it seems to work fine, although the temperature change still occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The demo files are gcode files generated for use with the sample PLA that comes with the printer. If you want to print it with ABS select the file and set the temperature manually afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the demo files, you can probably pause the print as soon as it starts, and manually set the extruder temperatures before resuming the print. Easier to generate new g-code though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the demo files with ABS rather than PLA, as the files are designed to do, I recommend loading the file into CURA and saving out a new gcode file with the adjusted temperatures. You can load the file from gcode, which will give you the basic settings that are included in the PLA file. I would also recommend slowing down the first layer a bit as adhesion of the initial layer is much more important for ABS than PLA, as ABS tends to warp more. Also you should reduce, if not turn off your cooling fans. Then once all the settings are where you need them to be for ABS, just export out a new file and probably change the name to include _ABS so you know the difference when you're mounting the card.